# Hibernate with PostgreSQL on Heroku error creating table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, javalin

I'm getting this error when building a Javalin app that uses Hibernate with PostgreSQL.
All the other tables are being created normally but this one gives me this error and I can't figure out why. I have seen this error but it happens when using the "user" as a table name may be sale is a postgre reserved name for an internal table.

```
2021-06-24T18:43:16.449969+00:00 app[web.1]: Jun 24, 2021 6:43:16 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
2021-06-24T18:43:16.449977+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table sale (id  serial not null, date date, user varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
2021-06-24T18:43:16.449978+00:00 app[web.1]: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table sale (id  serial not null, date date, user varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

The sale class hibernate annotations are like so:

```java
@Entity
public class Sale implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column()
    private String user;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale")
    private Set<SoldProduct> products = new HashSet<>();
    @Column()
    private LocalDate date;

    public Sale(){
        this.date = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public Sale(String user, Set<SoldProduct> products){
        this.user = user;
        this.products = products;
        this.date = LocalDate.now();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Set<SoldProduct> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<SoldProduct> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void addProduct(SoldProduct product){
        products.add(product);
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

I'm using java 11, hibernate 5.5.3 with PostgreSQL95Dialect on Heroku PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user column is a reserved word in postgres. Try to change it to something else.

Example:

```
@Column(name = "account_user")
private String user;
```

Comment: That was the fix, never thought of it, thank you so much!!!!!